# Query Contact members from a specified group?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I need to fetch the members for a specific group in android contacts.

I have the contact group names and their ID's

Can anyone provide me how to query the contacts provider for members in a particular group ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this method:

```
private Cursor getContacts(String groupID) {
   Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

   String[] projection = new String[] {
       ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
       ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
       ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
   };

   String selection = null;
   String[] selectionArgs = null;

   if(groupID != null && !"".equals(groupID)) {
       selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID
                   + " = ?";
       selectionArgs = new String[] { groupID };
   }
   else
       selection = "1) GROUP BY (" + ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID;

       String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
                          + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC ";

       return getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, 
                                         selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

This works on Android 2.3.3 and lower, but doesn't work on Android 4+ and I don't currently know why.

**UPD.**

Adding custom string parameter "GROUP BY" to SQL query is denied in Android 4+, so I've founded this workaround:

```
private Cursor getContacts(String groupID) {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;

    if(groupID != null && !"".equals(groupID)) {
        selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID 
                        + " = ?";
        selectionArgs = new String[] { groupID };
    }

    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
                        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC ";

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, 
                                          selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder); 

    MatrixCursor result = new MatrixCursor(projection);
    Set<Long> seen = new HashSet<Long>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long raw = cursor.getLong(1);
        if (!seen.contains(raw)) {
            seen.add(raw);
            result.addRow(new Object[] { cursor.getLong(0), 
                             cursor.getLong(1), cursor.getString(2) });
        }
    }

    return result;
```